# How to Unhook two hook procedures simultaneously?

Tags: windows, mouse, hook, mouse-hook

In my application I created two procedures namely callbackwnd procedure to handle focus events and mouse procedure to handle mouse click events.when I unhook the two procedure the application will flicker little bit.how to overcome this?

I also like to know which procedure is first to use unhook function ?

Regards,
Karthik

Comment: Windows, Linux? Where? What language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unhook any procedure at any time.preferably unhook the procedure while closing the window(WM_CLOSE).

The flickering may happened due to unhooking the function twice.

Comment: You haven't mentioned about flickering problem that happened while closing the window.